# Python using selenium webdriver to fill a form, when submitting the form, chrome is saying no internet connection is available

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver to fill out a form, the fields are good, but when I do a .submit using the login button, or do a .submit after the password field, the chrome browser will say "Unable to connect to internet. Please check your internet connection."

the internet is definitely up since I am able to open other websites on another browser (including a new session of chrome).

This is my code:

```
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('start-maximumized')
# options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
PATH = "c:\scripts\chromedriver.exe"
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, 
executable_path='c:\scripts\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stupidwebsite.org')
time.sleep(1)
input_username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')

time.sleep(1)
input_username.send_keys("myself@email.com")

input_password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
input_password.send_keys("mypassword@123")
input_password.submit()
# esubmit=driver.find_element_by_xpath
('/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/button')
# esubmit = driver.find_element_by_name('MuiButton-label')
# esubmit.submit()

time.sleep(2)
# driver.quit()
```

I changed it a bit, and tried out google, and it works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
#set chromodriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\scripts\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
#launch URL
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
#identify search box
m = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
#enter search text
m.send_keys("Tutorialspoint")
time.sleep(0.2)
#perform Google search with Keys.ENTER
m.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: if you are facing no internet connection is available error this is not the issue with selenium, you have to check your application or webservices , also as you said, I changed it a bit, and tried out google, and it works:, So it's clear the issue is with your application..

Comment: I am just not sure what I have done wrong, almost the same code, they all open up chrome, put in some info, and then submit. The webservice shall be good since it works for both.

Comment: Are you getting the same error, when you do the same action manually ?

Comment: When I do it manually without the script, it works. Also when I ran the script without doing the submit click, I also got a internet connection not available when I click on the login button. I am wondering do my code turn the chrome into a kiosk mode?

Comment: I think it may be the driver.get statement that turns the chrome browser to the offline mode. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting this problem only in case of Chrome? Have you check on other browser?

Comment: Also any proxy settings on this machine?

Comment: No proxy on this workstation

Comment: I also tried Firefox, same issue

Comment: This works:    
  driver.get('https://booking.kscgolf.org.hk/login')  
  time.sleep(2)  
  input_username = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")    
  input_username.send_keys("simonemail@simon.com")  
  input_password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")  
  input_password.send_keys("abcd1234")  
  time.sleep(1)  
  esubmit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/button")   
  esubmit.submit()